# CodeIgniter session shows different output in different functions

Tags: codeigniter

In first function of my controller, I am fetching random records from mysql table using CI active record

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions WHERE `level` = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,5");
$result = $query->result_array();
```

and saving result in session as

```
// saving questions id in session
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{
    $session['questionsId'][] = $result[$i]['qId'];
}
$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

and if print session variable it shows output like:

```
$qIds_o = $this->session->userdata('questionsId');
var_debug($qIds_o);

Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 11
)
```

but if I retrieve same session in another function of same controller it shows different result

```
$qIds = $this->session->userdata('questionsId');
var_debug($qIds);

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
```

and if I remove `ORDER BY RAND()` from mysql query like:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions WHERE `level` = '1' limit 0,5");
```

it shows same session array in both functions. Very strange.

### Please guide what is going wrong....

Here is my controller script:

```
public function set_value(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions WHERE `level` = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,5");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    // saving questions id in session
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
        $session['questionsId'][] = $result[$i]['qId'];
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata($session);
    $qIds_o = $this->session->userdata('questionsId');
    var_debug($qIds_o);
}

public function get_value(){
    $qIds = $this->session->userdata('questionsId');
    var_debug($qIds);
}
```

I called `set_value()` on page load while once the page loaded I call `get_value()` using `AJAX post` which simply hits `my_controller/get_value/` and response back to browser.

Comment: So your code to save random question ids into the session obviously runs twice - find out why. Either the method is called again, or your sessions are not working, f.e. because of blocked cookies.

Comment: cookies are unblocked I have checked using by 'navigator.cookieEnabled' 
and i am calling first function only once where query is executing & setting session. Only getting session values once it set.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your controller (let's call it `my_controller` in detail, I think what might be happening is:

(1) You call the first function, `my_controller/set_value` where `set_value` sets the session variable and you echo the result.

(2) You then call the second function, `show_value` that simply echos out the session variable.

What you might be doing in `set_value` is:

1) echo out the current session variable
2) call the query and re-set the session variable

If this is the case, then when you go to `show_value` (2nd function) you are looking at the recently re-set value instead of the prior value that you echoed out in the first function.

Comment: Thanks: no, I updated my question with my exact script now please have a look and point where I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is your AJAX call set up?

Comment: Somehow, `set_value` is getting called more than once.  But where? As a diagnostic, may I suggest that you store a time stamp as a session value (e.g. now() is good enough) and echo it out?  We want to make sure that `set_value` is being called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions about this sentence:

> but if I retrieve same session in another function of same controller it shows different result

1. Is this on a new page load?
2. If so, is the query run *again*?

I'm going to assume the answer to both of these questions is yes, since you said removing `RAND()` gives you the same results.

You are using a combination of `RAND()` and `LIMIT` in your query, meaning you want only five rows in a random order. That means that each time the query is run (and your session data is set), it is **very** likely that the results will be different.

I don't know exactly what you're doing with these IDs and what sort of data set you need, so this may not be 100% perfect for your solution, but if you only need to set this session data once, you should check if it exists before running the query.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('questionsId') === FALSE)
{
    // Run your query and set your session data here.
    // Note that in CI 3.0, Session::userdata()
    // will return NULL if empty, not a boolean.
}
```